# Displaying posts from a custom category

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I would like to display a certain number of posts that belong to a specific custom category.

In my WordPress admin, we have Movies as general/global section under which we found:

- Movies (List of all movies)
- Add new movie
- Movie Genre:

  - Movie genre 1
  - Movie genre 2
  - Movie genre 3
  - ...

For example, how would I display all movies that belong to Movie Genre 2?

The code below is for assistance, it displays all movies:

```
$rate_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
    'post_type' => 'movies', 
    'posts_per_page'=>'5' 
) ); 
while ( $rate_query->have_posts() ) : $rate_query->the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) is the place to look for this :)

In particular, you're after the [taxonomy query parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters). Adding a `tax_query` to your code will look like this:

```
$rate_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
    'post_type' => 'movies', 
    'posts_per_page'=>'5',
    'tax_query' => array(
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
         'field' => 'slug',
         'terms' => array( 'movie-genre-2' ),
       ),
    ),
) );
```

Then just adjust the slugs of both your taxonomy and terms to match how they are defined. You can also include multiple terms.

In addition, there's a lot more fine-grained control you can add to the query if you like, which is covered in the aforementioned docs.

Comment: Thank you Tim for the quick reply, actually i followed your code but nothing happens! what i did is as follows: '$rate_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
    'post_type' => 'movies', 
    'posts_per_page'=>'5',
    'tax_query' => array(
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'spanish-movies',
         'field' => 'slug',
         'terms' => array( 'movie-genre' ),
       ),
    ),
) ); '

Comment: @Webjectif Just to clarify, have you also included the `while` loop in your original code?

Comment: yes i did and here is a preview of my code (http://txt.do/5iujm)

Comment: @Webjectif That link doesn't work. Oh, I just noticed you might've got the taxonomy and term around the wrong way - movie-genre should be the taxonomy and spanish-movies the term :)